# iterate over pyspark Dataframe and then for each row interact with mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo-3.x

I have a pyspark Dataframe and now i want to iterate over each row and insert/update to mongoDB collection.

```
 #Did every required imports 
 #dataframe
 +---+----+
 |age|name|
 +---+----+
 | 30|   c|
 |  5|   e|
 |  6|   f|
 +---+----+
  db = mongodbclient['mydatabase']
  collection = db['mycollection']
  #created below function to insert/update
  def customFunction(row):
      key = {'name':row.name}
      data = dict(zip(columns,[row.x for x in columns]))
      collection.update(key, data, {upsert:true})
      #return a_flag #commented it as of now, a_flag can be 0 or 1
```

If a name exist in the mongoDB collection 'mycollection' it should update that row/record else insert that new record.

i am getting following error when tried to map this function over spark-dataframe

```
 result = my_dataframe.rdd.map(customFunction)
 #.....TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects....
 #AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Can anybody please figure out 'what is wrong here in that function and/or anywhere else' or please suggest if any other alternative is there to this type of task.

Basically iterate each row(without a collect call is that even possible??)

And, on each row apply  a function to run outside-spark work.

Please suggest, Thanks in Advance..:)

My data in mongoDB

```
name  age
 a    1
 b    2
 c    3 #new update should make age as 30 and 2 more new recs should inserted
```

Comment: How big is the dataset `my_dataframe`? Does export need to be run in parallel? Because there are at least 3 valid ways to achieve what you need, depending on how many records do you have to update.

Comment: @Mariusz: Base_collection in mongoDB has around 150mln+ records and spark-dataframe will have a incremental data not more than 500000 records. Plz let me know what are the options available.

Comment: @Mariusz: I generally does not prefer collect or conveting into pandas dataframe and then upsert into MongoDB.

Comment: @Satya how do you insert your bulk rdd then?

Comment: @ShaikRizwana: My code works after following user8371915's answer(connection object cannot be pickled, created the conn object inside Customfunction). And this approach is faster than Mariusz's approach(I still don't understand why!!!). Actually I have changed my storage to HDFS from Mongo, and doing Aggregation on whole dataset everytime and updating the complete resultset(yes strange but i have other dependencies, so i had to change.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like connection object cannot be pickled. I'd use `foreachPartition`:

```
def customFunction(rows):
    db = mongodbclient['mydatabase']
    collection = db['mycollection']

    for row in rows:
        key = {'name':row.name}
        data = dict(zip(columns,[row.x for x in columns]))
        collection.update(key, data, {upsert:true})

my_dataframe.rdd.foreachPartition(customFunction)
```

but keep in mind that fatal failure might leave the database in inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 500k records to be upserted in MongoDB the bulk mode will be probably more efficient way to handle this. Executing requests inside mongoDB will require much more power compared to what you actually do in spark (just creating requests) and even executing this in parallel may cause instabilities on mongo side (and be slower than "iterative" approach).

You can try the following code. It does not use `collect()`, so it's memory efficient on driver:

```
bulk = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for row in rdd.toLocalIterator():
    key = {'name':row.name}
    data = dict(zip(columns,[row.x for x in columns]))
    bulk.update(key, data, {upsert:true})

print(bulk.execute())
```